# Como mostrar en una tabla campos con todos los valores distintos en MySql?

Tags: mysql

Ésta pregunta por ahi ya la hicieron pero no encuentro una que me ayude.

El problema que estoy teniendo es que no puedo mostrar el registro con la fecha mas reciente a la de hoy. Me explico...

si tengo dos registros con los siguientes datos (son los mismos menos la fecha:

```
| Entrega |  Pedido  | Remito | Cant. Imagenes|    Fecha   |   Hora   |
| 11111111| 22222222 | 333333 | 10            | 2022-11-29 | 12:12:40 |
| 11111111| 22222222 | 333333 | 10            | 2022-12-22 | 14:48:02 |
```

Les muestor como se me ve a mi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El registro que quiero mostrar en mi tabla es el segundo(que es el que más cercano a la fecha actual es)...

ésta es la consulta que estoy utilizando

```
consulta = "SELECT e.Entrega, p.Pedido, p.Remito, e.Fecha from Entrega e INNER JOIN Pedido p ON e.Entrega = p.Entrega WHERE e.Fecha BETWEEN '" + desdeFecha + " 00:00:00' AND '" + hastaFecha + " 24:00:00' ORDER BY e.Pedido";
```

Probé con `DISTINCT`, `DISTINCTROW`, `ORDER BY`, pero no logro poder resolver mi problema

Comment: ¿Tal vez ordenando por ambas columnas y limitando a 1 la salida? `... ORDER BY e.pedido, e.fecha DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Pero el registro mas cercano es el de diciembre, el 2 no el primero que es de noviembre. Igual un Limit 1 no te ayudaría???

Comment: Es verdad @OCHOA me confundí, ya lo corrijo

Comment: @MauricioContreras no me funcionó che, hice el cambio y subi una imagen hoy, pero en la tabla me sigue figuarando la fecha 2022-12-22 en vez de 2023-01-10

Comment: Sigo sin ver el Limit en tu query :-s

Comment: @OCHOA pero si pongo LIMIT 1 me va a traer solamente 1 registro, cuando en un rango de fechas me puede traer más de 1000...

Comment: Entonces te tocara cambiar el **ORDER BY e.Pedido** y hacerlo que te ordene por la fecha que tu quieres. Es difícil replicar sin tener la estructura de las tablas, pero creo que con un **ORDER BY e.entrega DESC** te lo ordenaría.